# Use a defined Variable as part of Path name in R

Tags: r, file, csv, path, read.csv

Hello everybody I have the following problem:
With the R script im writing, I wish to use a variable that is to be given by the user, as a part of the file path the programm is to open. The code looks like this:

```
options(max.print=9999999)

$n <- readline(prompt="Input Analysis Nr: ")

d20 = read.csv("C:/Documents/Analysis/$n/$n_20.csv", header = TRUE, row.names=NULL)
```

As you can see, im trying to define the path of the file with the input of the variable $n. Wenn I run the script, the value of $n isnt shown in the file path and I receive an error, since there is no file with that name. 
Do you have an idea of what the correct syntax for this is?

Thanks in advance,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
n <- readline(prompt = "Input Analysis Nr: ")

d20 <-
  read.csv(
    paste0("C:/Documents/Analysis/", n, "/", n, "_20.csv"),
    header = TRUE,
    row.names = NULL
  )
```

Also, I'm getting an error using `$n` as variable. I guess because `$` is used to adress variables in data frames it can not be used in a variable name.